# Which is more easier to understand Laravel or Yii framework for beginners?

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel, yii, frameworks

I just want to ask your opinion about this. I am planning to switch my framework CodeIgniter into Laravel or Yii. I tried installing them and study a little and there are all great framework. I have a project for 1 month and I want to use a new frameworK for this project. This project is just a simple Blogging site. I also have a knowledge in Opencart an Ecommerce framework. And iT is much the same as CodeIgniter. That's why I learned it so fast. Now my problem is if I used these framework which is Laravel or Yii can I learn it easily? Or I have to spent a month for learning this? What I want to do is learning these framework while doing. But I am afraid that I can make it to the deadline.

Can you help m what framework should I need to use?

I have a knowledge in HMVC-L but not so professional and simple Ajax process.

Comment: Go for Laravel ofcourse. It started some time in 2011 and version 5 is set to release anytime soon. Jeff Way is always there to help you at www.laracasts.com

Comment: or check yii2, it's awesome too

Comment: Choice is not a problem at all, but having lack of choices is always a problem. I use laravel and go together with it. Also learning from it. As it says, it is for web artisans :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a very wide question.

If you are using CodeIgniter, what are the problems that you are facing that you need to shift to another framework? In my opinion, stick with CodeIgniter, and try to build your blog application with Code Igniter, you dont need to shift your framework. Also the documentation is good.

Even then if you would like to switch, make sure to check followings about that framework:

- How often they release their updates? More frequency, the better.
- How active is their community?
- How is their documentation?

For Code Igniter, all the above mentioned 3 are GREAT for beginners!

**Update[22/06/2015]:** Codeigniter 3 is now under active development, has a new home, and even has a dedicated website: [codeigniter.com](http://codeigniter.com) –  dotslash

Comment: Ok but I read some articles in the Web that CI is dead and no longer maintain the codes in the latest PHP5. I loved CI so much but I think I need to improve my knowledge as well. Just like learning other things. I scan their documentation and I found out that the CI documentation is much grater comparing to them. I am planning to choose Yii because their I think their documentation is much easier than Laravel. But I am not confident with myself that I can learn it while doing the project. :(

Comment: If you are changing framework, a learning curve will be there off course! At this point for a blog application and keeping in view your beginner's level, I dont think you need to follow all the software engineering principles etc and go for something else (so no need for Larvel at this point). Probably CI guys are building something new soon to support PDOs and other stuff. About PHP5, I built a payment gateway on PHP 5.6 using CI, so yes, dont worry for a blog :)

Comment: To be honest, I think it is a much wiser choice to drop CodeIgniter for Yii or Laravel! CodeIgniter has not been maintained for pretty much a year and is not a product of EllisLab anymore.. In 2013 there has been only 1 small update and in 2014 again only 1 small update, the community used to be great, but it is no surpise that it isn't anymore. Loads of people started looking at other frameworks.. So my advice, drop CodeIgniter and start learning another framework today ;)

Comment: Update: Codeigniter 3 is now under active development, has a new home, and even has a dedicated website: http://www.codeigniter.com/

Answer (score 3):

Most modern PHP developers use Laravel. And you should use Laravel too.

Laravel ensures best practices, has great wrappers and teaches you a lot about PHP. It's well documented and insanely well written to make it easy to adapt to.

You should most certainly NOT USE CODEIGNITER - it's a very wide opinion that CodeIgniter is not up to par with modern frameworks like Laravel or CakePHP anymore.

Laravel dictates all sorts of best practices, standards and procedures you need to be a good efficient developer and has a massive array of packages for deployment.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. I will try to learn basic stuffs from Laravel this week. And hopefully I can easily learn. :)

Comment: Let me provide link to good article http://yii2framework.wordpress.com/2014/03/15/yii-2-0-vs-laravel/

Comment: There is a newer version of the comparison: https://yii2framework.wordpress.com/2015/02/21/yii-2-vs-laravel-5/

Comment: I tried learning Lumen before Laravel :)

Comment: Most of modern PHP developers that *I know* are using Yii 2 (me included :). I could say the same: "Yii2 ensures best practices, has great wrappers and teaches you a lot about PHP. It's well documented and insanely well written to make it easy to adapt to... Yii2 dictates all sorts of best practices, standards and procedures you need to be a good efficient developer and has a massive array of packages for deployment." But it would be a very **vague** answer.

Comment: By `Most modern PHP developers` I construe you're talking about inexperienced ones.

Answer (score 1):

I think that structure is more or less same (MVC) which is similar to Codeigniter. So if you know how MVC works then this two frameworks wont be that much hard to learn. And about time to learn, well it depends on the capability of a person. But if you want to switch to a stable something, then i will suggest you to test run with Zend Framework (Not suggesting to build your current work with this) when you feel like it. Coz its more stable and reliable. :)

Comment: Ok thanks. I tried to study Zend last month and I am having a hard time with this. All their codes is so complicated for me to understand. Because I am an amateur PHP programmer. And I read some comparison in the Web that Zend is just like a monster in PHP frameworks. That's why I didn't continue studying this. I think in the future I will try to study it again so that I can learn Magento as well.. :)

Comment: Do you need any help regarding clearing your MVC concept? Coz i think if your concept is not clear that much, you will face difficulty like i did. Let me know. :)

Comment: As for now I don't have any problem with MVC concept. But I admit that sometimes I didn't follow the correct structure of MVC. Sometimes I include my query in the View which is a bad practise but I am trying to avoid that.. :)

Comment: Well we all do same sometimes lol. If you have time you can read this article which helped me a lot: http://teknoid.wordpress.com/2009/01/06/another-way-to-think-about-mvc/. -Regards :)

Comment: Ok thanks for the link I will read it now.. :)